# JavaScript: Syntax Checking

Tags: javascript, ide, syntax-error

Probably the most infuriating part of writing JavaScript is how it silently collapses on syntax errors. In particular a missing quote or brace can wipe out the whole script.

It’s not hard to pick up on many runtime errors with a combination of `'use strict'` and `window.onerror`.

Many coding IDEs offer some sort of syntax checking, often though addons such as `jshint`.

Is there any way to get JavaScript to report on its own syntax errors?

Alternatively, I would be happy for a recommended IDE which truly debugs Browser-Based JavaScript.

Edit:

JavaScript obviously goes through a parsing stage and syntax errors obviously cause it grief. Does the parser itself report errors in any catchable way?

I am aware that 3rd party linters are of use here, but I wondered whether JavaScript itself offered a clue.

Comment: `Is there any way to get JavaScript to report on its own syntax errors?` what a magnificent idea! It was so good, I just travelled back in time to implement it and now, and before, you will be getting the syntax errors reported.

Comment: Try https://atom.io/ and add the linter package, with linter-jshint.

Comment: @vlaz Most amusing. JavaScript has the `SyntaxError` object which represents syntax errors (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError). The sample uses `eval` which, no doubt, some clever wit will say is Evil. The point is there may be a way to catch this oneself. I suspect that that’s a technique that many consoles apply.

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. Syntax errors can already - except for runtime compilation that throw a catchable error - be detected befor depolyment using jshint or in your unit tests. Add them to you deployment step and you wouldn't need detect them in the browser. So why do you want to detect them in production code in the browser?

Comment: @t.niese I didn’t say that I wanted the errors raised in production code in the browser. If you are missing a closing brace on line 3 of your 400 line script, the whole thing fails. jsHint is more worried about the missing semicolon, and unit tests won’t even work.

Comment: `jsHint is more worried about the missing semicolon` I'm using ESLint in my projects and tried removing a closing brace - that is throwing a `Fatal: Parsing error`. Tried JSHint and it threw _2 errors_ caused by the same missing brace. Heck, even JSCS threw a hissy fit because it was parsing invalid JS code. In short, making one breaking change caused my IDE to light up like a Christmas tree. So, no, I don't think the linters are that useless as you make them out to be.

Comment: @vlaz Funny, my jsHint just flagged that as a warning. I might take a look at ESLint, though. Thanks

Comment: @Manngo  jshint or jslint do syntax checking. So if there is a synax error then it is reported. If you add them to you CI -Test then you will alway know that there is a syntax error when you changed something.

Comment: I don't think JSHint differentiates between warnings and errors - anything that violates its rules or parsing, I believe, is thrown as a problem. At least in the IDEs I've used, you can then show that problem as either warning or error. ESLint gives you more fine-grained control to determine whether any of its rules result in warning or error and it gives the more explicit parsing error when it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does not "silently collapse" on syntax errors in modern browsers (for that matter, it didn't even on older browsers). Open the dev tools (Ctrl+Shift+I and/or F12, or Cmd+Shift+I on Macs) and look at the console. It will show you syntax errors, usually with a link directly to the relevant line of code. Those same dev tools also provide a fully-featured debugger.

> JavaScript obviously goes through a parsing stage and syntax errors obviously cause it grief. Does the parser itself report errors in any catchable way?

Yes — to its caller, which will be in the environment in which the parser is running, not your code. Per spec, parsing invalid code results in a `SyntaxError`. It's up to that environment to then report that error to you.

Comment: JavaScript does indeed silently fail, if you prefer, unless you run it in an environment which picks up the errors. I use Komodo Edit, among many others, which uses jsHint to look for these, but that is not the same as finding fundamental errors. Browsers today do a good job, and I use them routinely, but they’re hardly a coding environment. See my edit above (when I have finished it) for clarification.

Comment: @Manngo: With respect, but no, it doesn't. Evaluating script code with a syntax error raises a `SyntaxError` per specification. It's up to the environment to report that error.

Comment: OK, I see your point: the parser reports on errors, but the coding environment may or may not pass it on. Browsers do in the development tools. Would that be right?